# git lfs, store file in actual location

Tags: git, git-lfs

**The problem**

A while ago my team started using git LFS, our project uses about 60 GB bmp files. I pushed the bmp files from my system to the remote, all images are correctly stored on LFS.

Whenever a colleague pulls the repository something weird happens, the bmp files are downloaded but stored in a different location. The image folder now contains a bunch of useless pointers instead of the actual images.

**Desired solution**

The image files are stored in their actual location instead of a useless pointer. In other words, I want the lfs files to behave like all the regular files.

Comment: When using the LFS wrapper around Git, all *Git* **stores** are the pointer files. It's the wrapper's job to replace these with the contents of the pointed-to files. Anyone getting just the pointer files is not using the LFS wrapper. Figure out why he's not using the wrapper, and correct that.

Comment: @torek What do you mean by "using the LFS wrapper"? Are there different commands when using lfs? | The images are downloaded to the local system but are stored in the .git folder instead of the images folder.

Comment: Git-LFS is or was add-on software (it may now come with its own Git implementation to avoid some confusion; originally it was some scripts to add to any standard Git). If you use plain Git, you're not using Git-LFS, and will see all the pointer files. I don't actually use Git-LFS myself but I've looked at it somewhat, and the implementation relies on "clean" and "smudge" filters in Git—so if you take a plain Git and add the add-ons but don't actually hook them up, you'll have the same problem.

Comment: Using `git lfs clone` and `git lfs init` instead of `git clone` and `git init` should establish all the right filtering. Using `git clone` instead ... won't.

Comment: @torek we managed to pull the images to their actual location. Now there is a duplicate of each image in the `.git/fls` folder. I don't understand why git-lfs is acting what way.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Git LFS to check out the files on your system properly, you need to have installed the Git LFS software and run `git lfs install` at least once, or have otherwise configured the filters propely.  On some systems, like Debian (and, I believe, when using Git for Windows), this is already configured for you, but otherwise, you need to run that command.

Once you do that, further checkout and clone operations will result in the files behaving very much like normal.  If you want to fix the existing files in your working directory, try `git lfs pull`, which should result in those files being properly checked out.